# Add to Linear Layout ProgressBar programatically

Tags: android, android-studio

I would like to add a progressbar to the right of my checkbox, checkboxes are created programatically

this is how i create the checkboxes programatically

```
private void setCheckBoxesCelle(){
        int id_ord_trasp = celle_bsm.getOrdTrasp();
        ArrayList<String> celle_motrice = celle_bsm.getCelleAutomezzo(id_ord_trasp,false,true);
        ArrayList<String> celle_rimorchio = celle_bsm.getCelleAutomezzo(id_ord_trasp,true,true);
        HashMap<String, CheckBox> hm = new HashMap();
        Resources r = getResources();
        float width = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 110, r.getDisplayMetrics());
        float width_short = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 70, r.getDisplayMetrics());
        float height = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 110, r.getDisplayMetrics());
        float height_short = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 70, r.getDisplayMetrics());
        float text_size = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 35, r.getDisplayMetrics());
        float text_size_short = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 10, r.getDisplayMetrics());
        HashMap<String, TextView> hmt = new HashMap();

        for(int i= 0 ; i<celle_motrice.size(); i++){
            CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(this);
            TextView txt = new TextView(this);
            lmcc = celle_bsm.getLastLogMovimentiCelleCisterne(celle_motrice.get(i));
            LinearLayout appoggio = new LinearLayout(this);
            if(sv_celle_lbl.getTextSize() != getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.fab_margin)){

                LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams((int) width, (int) height);
                lp.setMargins(10,5,10,5);
                cb.setLayoutParams(lp);
                cb.setText(celle_motrice.get(i));
                cb.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.checkbox_background));
                cb.setButtonDrawable(null);
                cb.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                cb.setTextSize(text_size);
                cb.setClickable(false);
            }else {

                LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams((int)width_short, (int)height_short);
                lp.setMargins(10,5,10,5);
                cb.setLayoutParams(lp);
                cb.setText(celle_motrice.get(i));
                cb.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.checkbox_background));
                cb.setButtonDrawable(null);
                cb.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                cb.setTextSize(text_size_short);
                cb.setClickable(false);
            }
            hm.put(celle_motrice.get(i),cb);

            appoggio.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            txt.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

            appoggio.addView(cb);
            appoggio.addView(txt);
            hmt.put(celle_motrice.get(i),txt);

            sv_linear_layout_celle.addView(appoggio);
            cb.getRootView();

        }
```

i dont know if it's possible, i've tried to add but simply add a blank space

i would add the progressbar to the right of the checkboxes like the photo.

if you need more details please contact me

now i would like add the progressbar near the checkboxes like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tu0Zf.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code below and let me know if it works-

```java
    private void setCheckBoxesCelle(){
        int id_ord_trasp = celle_bsm.getOrdTrasp();
        ArrayList<String> celle_motrice = celle_bsm.getCelleAutomezzo(id_ord_trasp,false,true);
        ArrayList<String> celle_rimorchio = celle_bsm.getCelleAutomezzo(id_ord_trasp,true,true);
        HashMap<String, CheckBox> hm = new HashMap();
        Resources r = getResources();
        float width = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 110, r.getDisplayMetrics());
        float height = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 110, r.getDisplayMetrics());
        float text_size = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 35, r.getDisplayMetrics());
        HashMap<String, TextView> hmt = new HashMap();
    
        for(int i= 0 ; i<celle_motrice.size(); i++){
            CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(this);
            TextView txt = new TextView(this);
            lmcc = celle_bsm.getLastLogMovimentiCelleCisterne(celle_motrice.get(i));
            LinearLayout appoggio = new LinearLayout(this);
            LinearLayout horizontalLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
            horizontalLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    
            ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar(this, null, android.R.attr.progressBarStyleHorizontal);
            progressBar.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    
            if(sv_celle_lbl.getTextSize() != getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.fab_margin)){
    
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams((int) width, (int) height);
                lp.setMargins(10,5,10,5);
                cb.setLayoutParams(lp);
                cb.setText(celle_motrice.get(i));
                cb.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.checkbox_background));
                cb.setButtonDrawable(null);
                cb.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                cb.setTextSize(text_size);
                cb.setClickable(false);
            }else {
    
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams((int)width, (int)height);
                lp.setMargins(10,5,10,5);
                cb.setLayoutParams(lp);
                cb.setText(celle_motrice.get(i));
                cb.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.checkbox_background));
                cb.setButtonDrawable(null);
                cb.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                cb.setTextSize(text_size);
                cb.setClickable(false);
            }
            hm.put(celle_motrice.get(i),cb);
    
            appoggio.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            txt.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    
            horizontalLayout.addView(cb);
            horizontalLayout.addView(progressBar);
    
            appoggio.addView(horizontalLayout);
            appoggio.addView(txt);
            hmt.put(celle_motrice.get(i),txt);
    
            sv_linear_layout_celle.addView(appoggio);
            cb.getRootView();
    
        }
    }
```

Remember to call `progressBar.setProgress(int progress)` to update the progress whenever needed.